# Eclipse always starts with /root/workspace

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse is always starting with `/root/workspace` . I select `~/workspace` and check that I want to use this workspace only. But on every restart eclipse is trying to open with `/root/workspace`

Eclipse : Kepler

Ubuntu: 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go under preferences then type "`workspace`" in the search box provided
  to filter the list. Alternatively you can go to **General>Startup and
  Shutdown>Workspaces**.
- There you can set a flag to make Eclipse prompt you to select a
  workspace at startup by checking the "**Prompt for workspace at
  startup**" checkbox.
- You can set the number of previous workspaces to remember also.
  Finally there is a list of recent workspaces. If you just remove all
  but the one you want Eclipse will automatically startup with that
  workspace.